# Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Resume

Tags: updates, 18.04, suspend, power-management

I performed updates yesterday.  Now my Ubuntu 18.04 won't resume after power save turns off the screen from inactivity.  The back lite light on both my laptop computer & external monitor turns back on. I can move the mouse around the screen.  But my Ubuntu desktop or applications don't come back.  I must power off the computer and turn it back on to use it.

Comment: Hi Ron - we'll need a bit more information than that to be able to narrow down what's going on. Do you have nVidia graphics? What's your processor? Do you have the same problems with suspend or only when the screen switches off? Are you saying the screen is blank but with a mouse cursor that you can move?

Comment: I am having this issue on my macbook with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Did you find a solution?